# Calling native Android kernel function from user code

Tags: android

As my [Motorola i1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motorola_i1) refuses to light its LED in the usual programmatic way (using NotificationManager with LED on specified), I've dived into Android Cupcake's source code and found out that the native applications such as Calendar & Messaging do this using NotificationManagerService, which uses

```
IHardwareService.setLedState()
```

which, in turn, calls the

```
setLightFlashing_UNCHECKED()
```

function of the kernel (or is it a component other than the kernel?). 
How do I either instantiate the HardwareService implementing  IHardwareService, or call the setLightFlashing_UNCHECKED myself?

Answer (score 1):

You can't, applications don't have permission to directly access such hardware.